# I get my function on my render but I can't see it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I get my data with my fetch (it is working) - I put it on my componentdidmount, then I write my function to render my data.

I can see it on my console but it doesn't appeared on my screen:

also my code :

```
getMesCommentaires = () => {
    console.log("coucou");

    const headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      Authorization: "bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    });

    const options = {
      method: "GET",

      headers: headers,
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:8080/serveur/mesCommentaires", options)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(
        (responseObject) => {
          const mesCommentaires = responseObject;
          if (Array.isArray(mesCommentaires)) {
            this.setState({ commentaires: mesCommentaires });
          }
          console.log(this.state);
        },

        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };
```

My function :

```
 renderMesCommentaires = () => {
    return this.state.commentaires.map((element, index) => {
      return (
        <div  key={index}>
          <h1 className="statut">{element.nom}</h1>
          <h1 className="statut">{element.prenom}</h1>
          <h1 className="statut">{element.texte}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMesCommentaires();
  };
```

[image]

Comment: It appears the state is not what you expect it to be - `commentaires` is an array, but the values are (probably) undefined. Try adding `console.log(this.state.commentaires)` at the start of `renderMesCommentaires` to verify that you have the values you expect.

Comment: To render sth you need to have a **render** method. Try to change **renderMesCommentaires** to **render**.

Comment: @Kryten The values appears when i put the console.log at the start of rendermescommentaires

Comment: @jakubJanik i have renderMesCommentaires on my render :)